# integral of continuous function that does not represent power of $x$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

in book named Partial differential equation by   Eutiquio C. Young,   there exist such question :

Show that  there is no continuous function $f$ that satisfy

$x^n=\int_a^x \mathrm{f}(t)\,\mathrm{d}t$

unless $a=0$

first of all we know that

$\int_a^x \mathrm{f}(t)\,\mathrm{d}t=F(x)-F(a)$

where $F$ is integral of $f$.

let take simple function   $f(x)=1$ then integral of this function is $F(x)=x$
so we will have  $x-a$ from integral, now if $a=0$ then clearly we have  $x-0=x$  and it is exactly equal to  $x=x^1$ or  $n=1$, but now suppose that

$a\neq 0$  then we should have

$x^n=x-a$

if $n=2$

then we have

$x^2-x+a=0$

let take $a=-2$

$x^2-x-2=0$

$x_1=2$,  $x_2=-1$   so what is wrong ?

Comment: The identity $x^n=x-a$ that you obtain has to hold for all values of $x$, not for some of them.

Comment: when  question is : Show that there is no continuous function    i meant that there is not such function for  even at least value of  $a$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $a=0$, then (assuming that $n\ge 1$) you always have $x^n = \int_0^x nt^{n-1}dt$.

On the other hand, if $x^{n}=\int_a^x f(t)dt$ with $f$ being continuous. Take the limit of both sides $x\to a$ (they exist because the function are continuous). On the left side you obtain $a^n$, and the right side you obtain $0$, therefore necessarily $a=0$.

Comment: ok thanks my friend for help